# Reading XML through Powershell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a XML file set up like this (please note the escape characters with & in the second and third row):

```
<PDON>
      <PDON-USTampa-15StoneHengeRoadFL PDON="Tampa" />
      <PDON-USSeattle-17Angel&amp;MarkAve PDON="Seattle" />
      <PDON-ESMadrid-XavierMolin&iacute; PDON="Madrid" />
</PDON>
```

when I am trying to read the file with:

```
$mapxml = [xml](get-content $pdonmapfile)
$locationName = "PDON-" #+ whatever the location name is read from XML as it iterates through the XML 
$xpath = "/PDON/$locationName"
$lookupval = $mapxml.selectstringnode($xpath)
```

It is throwing error on the lines with & characters. Any help? I am guessing that the XML has to be read in a different way but not aware of the exact powershell syntax.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Your document is malformed, `&` cannot be part of an [XML name](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#NT-Name), (encoded or not)

Comment: Your XML is not well-formed. According to [W3C XML 1.0 specs - 2.3 Common Syntactic Constructs](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml), elements should be alpha characters and avoid symbolic or whitespace, though colon, underscore, hyphens, and middle dot is permitted.

Comment: You can replace those invalid characters before loading `[xml]((gc $pdonmapfile) -replace '&(\w+);','_$1_')` and then decode them individually.